# Splitting AngularJS Module Services Across Files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two AngularJS services:

**service1.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .factory('myService1', function() {
    return {
      myFunction: function(options) {
        if (options) {
          // do stuff
      }
    }
  };
});
```

**service2.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .factory('myService2', function() {
    return {
      myFunction: function(options) {
        if (options) {
          // do stuff
      }
    }
  };
});
```

I learned the hard way from the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) that this approach will basically remove myService1 because the module gets overwritten. My question is, do I have any options here? I would really like to be able to have my services defined in separate files. Yet, I only want one module.

Thank you for any insights.

Comment: If they must be the same module then you need them on the same file otherwise you can name them with different module names while you bring them all together into one main module that will inject them as dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the module just once:

```
angular.module('myModule', []);
```

And then use it as many times as you need it without setting the dependencies:

```
angular.module('myModule');
```

So either you define the module in a separate file, or if you define it in the first service, the second should look like this:

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .factory('myService2', function() { ... });
```

Comment: And when doing this, make sure the files are included in the correct order so you don't try to add services to a module that hasn't been declared yet.